# proof of primitive roots algorithm

Tags: primitive-roots

We know the following from elementary number theory:

(1) for $gcd(a,n) =1, a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 (mod \, n)$

(2) $ord_na \mid \phi(n)$

(3) $a$ is a primitive root $mod \, n$ iff $ord_na = \phi(n)$.

From (2), the only possible values of $ord_ma$ are divisors of $\phi(n)$.
So, to exclude $a$ as a primitive root $mod \,n$, it suffices to test if for any proper divisor of $\phi(n)$, say $k\,, a^k \equiv 1 \,(mod \,n$.

Now let's choose an arbitrary $\phi(n)$, with prime factorization $p_1p_2p_3.$  The $p$'s can be the same or different.  The set of the proper divisors of $\phi(n)$ is $\{p_1, \,\,p_2, \, p_3, \,p_1p_2, \,p_1p_3,\, p_2p_3\}$. If $a^{p_1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$, then there's no need to test $p_1p_2, \, p_1p_3\,$, e.g., $\,(a^{p_1})^{p_2} \equiv 1 \pmod n$.  It seems at least intuitive that the test set only has to include the PRIME divisors of $\phi(n)$.

Can anyone help formalize the latter paragraph into a proof (or has this already been done)?

Comment: Why couldn't the order be $p_1p_2$?

Comment: For example, $n=16$ has no primitive root, but the order of $3\pmod {16}$ is $4$, not $2$.  $\varphi(16)=8$ so if you only tested the primes, you'd incorrectly conclude that $3$ was a primitive root.

Comment: do you have a counterexample where $n$ is prime?

Comment: Well, every prime has a primitive root, of course.  Do you mean "is there an example where the order of an element, not a primitive root, mod $p$ is not itself a prime?"  The answer is, of course.  $4$ has order $9\pmod {19}$ for example.  To produce examples, just take a primitive root $\pmod p$ and raise it to an appropriate power.

Comment: I neglected to specify, but the algorithm in question is assuming that the modulus is prime.

Comment: That doesn't really change much, other than, of course, we do know in advance that there is always a primitive root modulo a prime.

Comment: What I'm looking for is if the above is a valid (and more computationally efficient) means of finding one primitive root of a prime, $g$.  The others are $g^k$ where $gcd(k, \phi(n) \equiv 1$.  Can I do this by testing only the distinct prime factors of $\phi(n)$?

Comment: I don't see how I could be any clearer:  If all you do is test prime orders then you can't , in general, identify primitive roots.

Comment: It's obvious that the existence of a primitive root $\pmod n$ implies the existence of an element of order $d$ for any divisor, $d$, of $\varphi(n)$.  Indeed, if $g$ is a primitive root and $\varphi(n)=d\times m$ then $g^m$ has order $d$.

Answer (score 1):

All of the following presupposes $gcd(a, n) \equiv 1$

Let $d$ be a divisor of $\phi(n)$ such that $a^d \equiv 1 \pmod n. $
If $d = \phi(n)/p^{*}$, where $p^*$ is a prime factor of $\phi(n)$, then $a$ is not a primitive root $\pmod n$ and we are done.

Otherwise, write $d=(p_1p_2...p_k)$, where the factors $p$ are not necessarily unique.  Write $\phi(n)$ as $d \cdot q^*$, where $q^*= (q_1q_2...q_k)$ where the factors $q$ are not necessarily unique.

Choose an arbitrary single prime factor of $\phi(n),\; q,$ from $q^*$ and write $\phi(n)=d \cdot q \cdot \frac{q^*}{q}$. Therefore, $\frac{\phi(n)}{q} = d \cdot \frac{q^*}{q}$.

From the specification of $d, \; a^{\frac{\phi(n)}{q}} = a^{d \cdot \frac{q*}{q}}=(a^d)^{\frac{q*}{q}} \equiv 1 \pmod n.$  So for any divisor of $\phi(n)$ that shows $a$ not to be a primitive root, there exists at least one prime factor of $\phi(n)$ such that $a^{\frac{\phi(n)}{q}} \equiv 1 \pmod n$, thereby demonstrating the same.  Therefore, the maximal calculation necessary to determine if $a$ is a primitive root$\pmod n$ is to calculate $a^{\frac{\phi(n)}{p_i}} \pmod n$ for each of the distinct prime factors, $p_i$, of $\phi(n)$.  Obviously, you can stop as soon as you return 1.

Here's a graphic illustration of an example.  We are choosing the prime factorization of $\phi(n)$ to be $pqrs$, where $p, q, r, s$ are distinct primes.  The function $f(x)$ is a Boolean function evaluating the truth value of $a^x \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

The columns of the table represent the set of variables based on the distinct prime factors that need to be evaluated and the rows represent all the divisors of $\phi(n)$, excluding 1 and $\phi(n)$ itself. $T$ at an intersection indicates that the column value stands as a witness for the row value, i.e., if the column value is true then the row value is true.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cdot & \small{f(\frac{\phi(n)}{s})=f(pqr)} &  \small{f(\frac{\phi(n)}{r})=f(pqs)} & \small{f(\frac{\phi(n)}{q})=f(prs)} & \small{f(\frac{\phi(n)}{p})=f(qrs)}\\
f(p) & T & T & T & F \\
f(q) & T & T & F & T \\
f(p) & T & T & T & F \\
f(s) & F & T & T & T \\
f(pq) & T & T & F & F \\
f(pr) & T & F & T & F \\
f(ps) & F & T & T & F \\
f(qr) & T & F & F & T \\
f(qs) & F & T & F & T \\
f(rs) & F & F & T & T \\
f(pqr) & T & F & F & F \\
f(pqs) & F & T & F & F \\
f(prs) & F & F & T & F \\
f(qrs) & F & F & F & T \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The important thing to note is that every row has at least one $T$ value, which is the same as saying every divisor of $\phi(n)$ that shows $a$ not to be a primitive root has at least 1 $a^{\frac{\phi(n)}{p^*}} \equiv 1 \pmod n$.  A similar construction can be made if the prime factors of $\phi(n)$ are not distinct, and yields a similar result.

Comment: A working JavaScript application implementing this algorithm is [here](http://www.waysidehealth.com/mathStuff/primitiveRoots.html)